# Study the improper integral for convergence and absolute convergence

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\int_1^\infty \cos( x^2\ln(x) )\ dx $$
here is an integration which I have to study for convergence and absolute convergence.

I cannot find f(x) and g(x) to use Dirichlet test.

(Hint: Use Dirichlet test+negation of Cauchy condition)

Comment: @OliverDiaz. It could converge

Comment: @OliverDiaz. Me too ! I just wrote *it could*. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: if you can provide a proof do that I will take my hat off and happily give you my vote.

Comment: @OliverDiaz.If I can do it, you take your hat off and you eat it. Is this OK ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I'd rather give you my vote... Maybe you can do one of you fine numerical estimates and get estimates form the length of the intervals $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ where $x^2_n\log(x_n)=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$. I suspect that the they grow polynomially. The relevance to this is that $\Big|\int^{x_{n+1}}_{x_n}\cos(x^2\log x)\,dx>\frac12(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ whence it would follows that along the sequence $\{x_n\}$, the integrals $\int^{x_n}_1\cos(x^2\log(x))\,dx$ diverges (being expressible as an alternating series whose $n$-th term does not converge to $0$)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a rigorous answer, but it seems that the improper integral in the OP converges based on numerical calculation done by @ClaudeLeibovici.

Define the function
$$F(x)=\int^x_1\cos(t^2\log(t))\,dt$$
and consider the intervals $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ where $x^2_n\log(x_n)=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$. The function $\phi:t\mapsto\cos(t^2\log(t))$ vanishes at each $x_n$, it has sign $(-1)^{n+1}$ in $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$, and $|\phi(x'_n)|=1$ for some point $x_n<x'_n<x_{n+1}$.
Since $g(t)=t^2\log(t)$ is monotone increasing, $x_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$. The calculations of Claude's suggests that the length $\Delta_n$ of $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ decays as
$$\Delta_n\sim\sqrt{ \frac{\pi }{2 n}}\log \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{e}\right) \big[\log(2\pi n)\big]^{-3/2}=O\big(n^{−0.372854}\big)$$
Notice that
$$\begin{align}
F(x_n)&=\int^{x_0}_1\phi(t)\,dt +\sum^n_{j=1}\int^{x_j}_{x_{j-1}}\phi(t)\,dt\\
\end{align}$$
and
$$
\frac12\Delta_n\leq \Big|\int^{x_j}_{x_{j-1}}\phi(t)\,dt\Big|\leq\Delta_n$$
Then, the series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\int^{x_n}_{x_{n-1}}\phi(t)\,dt$ would be a convergent alternating series. This would suggest that improper integral $\int^\infty_1\phi(t)\,dt$ converges. Still some additional works need to be done to address existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)$ not only along the sequence $x_n$.

Comment: Thanks for having done it ! I enjoy this type of cooperation. Cheers :-)

Comment: Numerical values added in my edit

Comment: Thanks for your offering to collaborate. Best regards.

Comment: I should be delighted. I just have coauthored a paper with an MSE user met during a similar ccoperation.

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussions in comments with @OliverDiaz
$$x^2_n\log(x_n)=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \implies x_n=\sqrt{ \frac{\pi  (2 n+1)}{W(\pi  (2 n+1))}}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.
So, the length of the interval
$$\Delta_n=x_{n+1}-x_n=\sqrt{ \frac{\pi  (2 n+3)}{W(\pi  (2 n+3))}}-\sqrt{ \frac{\pi  (2 n+1)}{W(\pi  (2 n+1))}}\tag1$$ is a decreasing function of $n$.
The expansion for large values of $n$ is quite difficult. So, assuming $W(y)\sim \log(y)$,we have the approximation
$$\Delta_n\sim\sqrt{ \frac{\pi }{2 n}}\log \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{e}\right) \big[\log(2\pi n)\big]^{-3/2}\tag 2$$ CHecking for a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & (2) & (1) \\
 5  & 0.214310 & 0.228359 \\
 10 & 0.147734 & 0.162283 \\
 15 & 0.118389 & 0.131434 \\
 20 & 0.101099 & 0.112808
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is not fantastic but, in my opinion, acceptable for the analysis.

Using a quick and dirty nonlinear regression for the model
$$\Delta_n=a\,n^b+c$$ using the values of $(1)$ tabulated for $1 \leq n \leq 100$, we have with $R^2=0.99936$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +0.481053 & 0.002469 & \{+0.476153,+0.485954\} \\
 b & -0.372854 & 0.006015 & \{-0.384793,-0.360915\} \\
 c & -0.042170 & 0.002965 & \{-0.048056,-0.036285\} \\
\end{array}$$

**Edit** *(after @OliverDiaz's answer)*

Computing

$$I_k=\int_1^{10^k}\cos( x^2\ln(x) )\, dx$$ we can see a quite fast convergence
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & I_k \\
 1 & 0.2559212210 \\
 2 & 0.2708833458 \\
 3 & 0.2701534539 \\
 4 & 0.2710161375 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty & 0.2701136093
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @OliverDiaz. I did my part. Now, please, you continue with your arguments. Cheers :-)

Comment: Not what I was expecting, but it seems that the integral will converge. I am writing my part our collaboration. The integrals $p_n=\Big|\int^{x_{n+1}}_{x_n}\cos(t^2\log(t))\,dt\Big|$ seem to decrease to $0$, from where the convergence of the alternating series $\sum_n(-1)^{n+1}p_n$ would appear to converge. A proper proof still eludes me, but maybe the ideas should be enough to suggest convergence.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Are you implementing numerical integration on FORTRAN, C, MatLab or any other Language?

Comment: @OliverDiaz. I started with computers 60 years ago and, for my needs (efficiency) there is only Fortran.

Comment: I still use fortran myself. I will then implement my numerical integration on fortran too.